# How to use dynamic Type Hints in Laravel method

Tags: dependency-injection, laravel-5.1, type-hinting

Basically I want to make code generic and use different Services upon given Route parameters.

## What is the proper and working way to achieve this?

**The following works:**

*Routes:*

```
Route::get('socialmediaAccount/authorize/twitter', function(TwitterApi $client){ return ['Works'];});
```

**That works as well:**

*Routes*

```
Route::get('socialmediaAccount/authorize/twitter', ['uses' => 'SocialmediaController@authorizeAccount']);
```

*Controller*

```
class SocialmediaController extends Controller
{
  public function authorizeAccount(TwitterApi $client)
  {
    return ['Works as well'];
    
  }
}
```

**Now I want to add facebook, the idea is this:**

*Routes*

```
Route::get('socialmediaAccount/authorize/{type}', ['uses' => 'SocialmediaController@authorizeAccount']);
```

*Controller*

```
class SocialmediaController extends Controller
{
  public function authorizeAccount($type)
  {
    if($type == 'twitter') {
      $client->call TwitterApi-method();     //????????????
      return ['???'];
    }
    if($type == 'facebook') {
      $client->call FacebookApi-method();    //????????????
      return ['???'];
    }
  }
}
```

**Since this didn't work I tried and failed with following:**

Now in the definition of my Controller method I can't use the Type Hint anymore, and if I try to create separate methods ala `authorizeTwitter` I can't call it with Type Hint. I tried following:

*Routes* - is the same

*Controller*

```
class SocialmediaController extends Controller
{
  public function authorizeAccount($type)
  {
    if($type == 'twitter') {
      $this->authorizeTwitter();
      return ['???'];
    }
    if($type == 'facebook') {
      $this->authorizeFacebook();
      return ['???'];
    }
  }

  private function authorizeTwitter(TwitterApi $client)    //????????????
  {
     call TwitterApi-method();
  }

  private function authorizeFacebook(FacebookApi $client)    //????????????
  {
     call TwitterApi-method();
  }
}
```

The error here is 'Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of ... TwitterApi, none given.

Comment: Why call the separate methods from the generic method? Seems like you have two routes with two separate actions. Single responsibility would be 2 routes and 2 methods instead of 1 route and 3 methods.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, I wasn't clear enough you are right. The 3rd part of my question was what I tried after failing with the optimal solution which would be one route, one method ;-) Thanks to Koga's answer I found the solution by adding `public function authorizeAccount($type, TwitterApi $twitterClient, FacebookApi $facebookClient)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use dependency injection on methods that you call manually. Only on route methods, because route methods will be resolved automatically.

This said the following should work:

```
class SocialmediaController extends Controller
{
  public function authorizeAccount($type, TwitterApi $twitterClient, FacebookApi $facebookClient)
  {
    if($type == 'twitter') {
      // do Twitter authorization using $twitterClient here
    }
    if($type == 'facebook') {
      // do Facebook authorization using $facebookClient here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I would have taken a couple of hours to come up with that. Can you edit your answer, get rid of the two private methods and modify the two authorizeAccount-lines like `$twitterClient-> do Twitter auth stuff here`? That was my original intention and how I did it in the end.

Comment: I have simplified my answer by dropping the private methods. So does the answer suit your original intention now?

Comment: Hi Koga, now the question (maybe you had it already there until I asked you to modify your answer): I have another method in this class. How would I call `$this->authorizeAccount` from here? with`($type)` it doesnt work, I also tried to do `$twitter = $this->app['TwitterApi']; ..same for facebook` and then `authorizeAccount($type, $twitter, $facebook);` which doesn't work either. Any clue how to achieve this? Is the right way to do this using a constructor and asigning the TwitterApi and FacbookApi here?

Comment: Here's the revisions link http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34234650/revisions. There you can see my unedited answer. ;)

Comment: Nice, and would you do rather that or put the dependency injection in a constructor?

Comment: Since you need the injections for only one method, I would inject the dependencies in the method (as shown in my answer) and not in a constructor.